# In Magento 1 if i try to delete over 50 products the site crashes

Tags: product, magento-1, delete

Is there anyway to solve this rather annoying issue?

Comment: how can try to delete?

Comment: i go onto product management and delete through there as i do not have access to the Cpanel

Comment: have you tried turning off indexing while you delete them? (set it to manual rather than save on update)

Comment: Are there any custom attributes created for the products or are there any custom modules which do some processing on products?

Comment: What kind of errors did you receive? please check the logs & reports.

Comment: it is unable to handle the request

Comment: do you want to delete all products or specific products? you can do it by script

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the server's memory? Sounds like it's reaching it's limit and hanging the process - have had similar issues in the past and it's usually always been the memory limit on the server.